# Can a merge Conflict still be merged

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a strange situation happen to me this week.

I made a code change on master and it was behind head, when I did the commit and tried to push it vs code did a push and then a pull but then did something strange it had a merge conflict and still push the code up to github, no warnings / errors.

Now the code i changed was not the code that had a merge conflict is was an older commit.

What I want to know is it possible to submit a merge conflict to github, is there not check on there end when someone does a push?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to `push` with conflict. What system would do is generally notify you about a change on a remote repository; asking you to `pull` changes and then `push` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the only way a merge conflict has been able to make it through a commit and push is if someone has "added" the conflicted file to be staged for the next commit before having actually resolved the conflict in code.

Git will consider a merge conflict "done" or "resolved" when you `git add` the file to be staged for a commit, regardless of the contents.

So it sounds like, somehow, someone mistakenly added a conflicted file to a commit and pushed the commit, without having resolved the conflict.

I hope this makes sense. Let me know I need to clarify anything.